# Change Navigation View Color Sencha Architect

Tags: sencha-architect

I'm starting with Senchar Architect 2 and I want to change the Navigation View Top bar color,

I want a red color on navigation bar, i saw another 2 questions but I don't undertood, have a simple way to change de color ? Using CSS or the Config Panel of sencha architect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you CAN change the color of your navigation bar in the config panel (like you did for the back button color yesterday) --> Style --> Background: red.

Also, I would suggest you to take a look at the SASS theming which is recommended by Sencha folks.

Here is the link:

http://vimeo.com/36917216